# Why is my attempt to manipulate this 1GB file in Node.js deleting its contents?

Tags: node.js

I'm simply trying to overwrite the contents of a pre-generated (written with `allocUnsafe(size)`) 1GB file via a 4 byte buffer at an iterating offset, and before I open the file descriptor, `fs.stat` and the Windows file system show the correct size. As soon as I open the file descriptor, it appears both in `fs.stat` and in the file system the file is empty:

```
let stats = fs.statSync(dataPath)
let fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"]
let fileSizeInMegabytes = fileSizeInBytes / 1000000
console.log("fileSizeInMegabytes", fileSizeInMegabytes) // => fileSizeInMegabytes 1000

fd = fs.openSync(dataPath, 'w')

stats = fs.statSync(dataPath)
fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"]
fileSizeInMegabytes = fileSizeInBytes / 1000000
console.log("fileSizeInMegabytes", fileSizeInMegabytes) // => fileSizeInMegabytes 0
```

Why is opening the file descriptor emptying my file? Surely I'm missing something obvious, but I can't see it.

Comment: File opening "w" truncates the file. You should use "r+" , find a list here https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags.

Comment: Good use of editing the question, recognizing there are actually 2 questions at hand, and splitting the rest off into a new question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Opening the file using the `w` flag truncates the file, i.e. removes any contents.

You should use `r+` to read and write to the file without wiping it clean.

For more info, check out the [Node docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_file_system_flags) and the answers on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1466000/difference-between-modes-a-a-w-w-and-r-in-built-in-open-function).

Comment: Thanks. Still having an issue with the correct flag, but it ends up being a different question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984177/why-is-node-js-complaining-err-out-of-range-if-the-offset-is-within-the-files-r