# Why is Node.js complaining ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE if the offset is within the file's range?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to overwrite some of the contents of a pre-generated 1GB file via a 4 byte buffer at an iterating offset.

Best I can tell, I'm using the correct flag:

```
const fd = fs.openSync(dataPath, "r+") // also tried "a+"
```

[image]

And the file size looks within range:

```
let stats = fs.statSync(dataPath)
let fileSizeInBytes = stats["size"]
let fileSizeInMegabytes = fileSizeInBytes / 1000000
console.log("fileSizeInMegabytes", fileSizeInMegabytes) // => fileSizeInMegabytes 1000
```

But when I try to write the updates:

```
const bufferSize = 74

let pointer = (timestampSet.size * 4) + 4
for (let j = 0; j < timestampSet.size; j++) {
  pointer += mapIterator.next().value * bufferSize
  const pointerBuffer = Buffer.alloc(4)
  pointerBuffer.writeUInt32BE(pointer, 0) // <Buffer 00 2e 87 e4>
  console.log("writing", pointerBuffer, "to file", dataPath, "at offset", j * 4)
  // writing <Buffer 00 2e 87 e4> to file E://data.odat at offset 4
  fs.writeSync(fd, pointerBuffer, j * 4, 4)
}
fs.close(fd).then(() => {
  console.log("write stream closed")
})

iterateProcess()
```

I get the error:

```
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]: The value of "length" is out of range. It must be <= 0. Received 4
```

Why is this error happening if the file has the correct size and the correct flag is used?

Comment: Ideally, questions contain a "minimal working example" -- complete, yet little, code that others can run. It's not the case here. So, without running it, I'd say you should re-check the `writeSync` arguments. `offset` refers to the buffer and it seems you meant specify the target location. `fs.writeSync(fd, pointerBuffer, 0, 4, j*4)` could be right. Check the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback)

Comment: @snwflk Yeah you're right. I read the docs many times over, I just repeatedly misunderstood the explanation of the args.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to misinterpret the `writeSync` arguments. `offset` refers to the position in the buffer, not in the file. For the address in the file, use `position`.

The error message comes from the fact that the system cannot find 4 bytes in the buffer starting *from the location in the buffer* you specified.

Your code should read:

```
fs.writeSync(fd, pointerBuffer, 0, 4, j*4)
```

From the [docs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_write_fd_buffer_offset_length_position_callback):

> `offset` determines the part of the buffer to be written, and `length` is an integer specifying the number of bytes to write.
>
> `position` refers to the offset from the beginning of the file where this data should be written. If `typeof position !== 'number'`, the data will be written at the current position. [..]